# How to process CSV files within a Matrix field?

Tags: entries, assets, matrix, field, upload

I'm trying to import and process CSV data within a matrix field.
My situation is the following:

I have a matrix field with one block and several fields inside. One of these is an asset field to upload a CSV file. Now I don't just need to upload this file to a specific destination but also directly want process the given data inside of my CSV file to write it into the database and also display the data in the backend after saving the entry. Furthermore I need to be able to edit the output of the CSV in the backend. The best case would be a table.
I specifically don't want to have a standalone plugin which provides the given data to a matching entry. That would kinda ruin the workflow for editors.
I would really love to have the upload inside of the suitable entry.

Maybe I'm just overlooking one simple solution but I don't see how I should do it.

I hope I explained it good enough and am looking forward to some solutions.

Thanks in advance and best regards,

JohN

Comment: I'm also interested in this question. I suppose one way to find out would be to try it and see where it takes me, but is there a chance someone solved this issue long ago?

Answer (score 3):

You're not overlooking anything. What you're asking for is not a core feature of Craft and probably will never be. There's also no plugin yet that does something like this.

So the only answer I can give you right now is that you have to find someone who makes such a plugin for you. The [jobs board](http://straightupcraft.com/jobs) on straightupcraft.com is probably a good address to find a developer.